# Shell script to Capture the file name and size in csv file and add header on that file

Tags: shell-script, files, csv

I have a number of zip files in a certain folder. I want to capture file name and the size of the files in a CSV format in day wise and put it in crontab so I can report on a daily basis, and then mail it in each report.

Files are in `/somedirectory/archive/test`:

```
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 AAAA AAAA 9.3M May  30 17:09 XXXXX_20140530_0401_28.txt.gz
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 AAAA AAAA 9.3M May  30 17:09 XXXXX_20140530_0401_29.txt.gz
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 AAAA AAAA 9.3M May  31 17:09 XXXXX_20140531_0401_01.txt.gz
```

Now I want to crate a cronjob to run everyday and capture the same CSV which we prepared in day wise.

example `test30052014.csv`:

```
"File Name","size","date"
"XXXXX_20140530_0401_28.txt.gz", "9.3","May 30"
"XXXXX_20140530_0401_29.txt.gz", "9.3","May 30"
```

`test31052014.csv`:

```
"File Name","size","date"
"XXXXX_20140531_0401_01.txt.gz", "9.3","May 31"
```

Comment: Why do you need the date in the CSV if it is already part of the filename. And I can recommend always using YYYYMMDD when using a date in the `.csv` filename (as with your tarfiles), so listing the files by filename orders them chronologically ( and you don't get May 30th next to June 30th).

Answer (score 1):

a simple way to do this would be  to put in a script:

```
#!/bin/bash    
echo "File Name,Size,date" > /tmp/output_file
ls -l --time-style=+%m.%d.%Y /path/to/file |grep -v "^total|^d"|awk '{print $NF","$4","$5 }'  >> /tmp/output_file
```

This will remove the sum up at the beggining of the ls and also exclude the directories.

Comment: Shell command using awk and an example of the time-style parameter. Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Go to where the files are located
cd /somedirectory/archive/test

# Save IFS variable (if needed) and set it to newline.
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")

# List the files and for each one save the size, time and name. Then, save results.
echo '"File Name","size","date"' > output.csv
for line in `ls -lrt *.txt.gz`; do
        size=$(echo $line |awk -F ' ' '{print $5}');
        date=$(echo $line |awk -F ' ' '{print $6" "$7}');
        file=$(echo $line |awk -F ' ' '{print $9}');
        echo '"'$size'","'$date'","'$file'"' >> output.csv
done

# Return IFS to original status.
IFS=$SAVEIFS

code=$?
exit $code
```

Result:

```
$ cat output.csv 
"File Name","size","date"
"0","Jun 3","XXXXX_20140530_0401_28.txt.gz"
"0","Jun 3","XXXXX_20140530_0401_29.txt.gz"
"0","Jun 3","XXXXX_20140531_0401_01.txt.gz"
```